# UI options arrangement, various ways

Tags: user-interface, user-controls

I have the following interface for image modification where there is a preview and the user can set options from a tabbed interface.
  [image]

**The problems with current interface are:**

1. There are different options for different parts if the image;
2. There are some common options with the elements;
3. There are around 350 options arranged in 7 different tabs and sub-menus;
4. Only some of the options fit in submenu and others I have to show on maximize;
5. It is very difficult for a novice user to find the options;
6. Since options are grouped based on different parts of the image that options can be applied to, users sometimes don't know If they can change something;
7. Too many steps needed to set an option.

**What I want is:**

1. Options arranged so that users can find the options quickly;
2. An interface that is more user-friendly and 'cool'.

What are the other ways I can arrange options and make them more usable?

I am allowed to rearrange the preview and options pane, change their sizes. I also have an unused space that is shown.

Can you give examples where such situations are handled well?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Belongs on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user interface design.